# HERE Public Transit API: Obtain station ids

Tags: here-api

I'm looking to obtain the next departures from a station using the next departures API that is in the documentation:

https://developer.here.com/documentation/public-transit/dev_guide/next-departures/by-ids-example.html

But I don't have the location or the name of the stations to get the data with the Transit Station Search API.

Is there any way to get the station IDs used in Public Transit API from the GTFS IDs or some other way?

Comment: Hi @Javier, the options to retrieve the station IDs are either with Lat/Long or Lat/long + name at this time.

Answer (score 0):

the options to retrieve the station IDs are either with Lat/Long or Lat/long + name at this time.